# Naming a Talend Custom Component - Not working except for tTutorialRow

Tags: java, xml, talend

I have been following the Talend [tutorial](https://help.talend.com/display/KBSTAGING/How+to+create+a+custom+component) on "How to Create a Custom Component". If I follow the example verbatim, with my files named as follows and placed inside of the folder `tTutorialRow`, the tutorial works:

```
tTutorialRow_java.xml
tTutorialRow_messages.properties
tTutorialRow_begin.javajet
tTutorialRow_main.javajet
tTutorialRow_end.javajet
```

This is using the following code:

tTutorialRow_java.xml:

```
<COMPONENT>
  <HEADER
    PLATEFORM="ALL"
    SERIAL=""
    VERSION="2.0"
    STATUS="ALPHA"
  
    COMPATIBILITY="ALL"
    AUTHOR="Talend"
    RELEASE_DATE="20070525A"
    STARTABLE="false"
  >
    <SIGNATURE/>
  </HEADER>
  
  <FAMILIES> 
    <FAMILY>Helium</FAMILY> 
  </FAMILIES> 
  
  <DOCUMENTATION>
    <URL/>
  </DOCUMENTATION>
  
  <CONNECTORS>
    <CONNECTOR CTYPE="FLOW" MAX_INPUT="1"/>
    <CONNECTOR CTYPE="ITERATE" MAX_OUTPUT="1" MAX_INPUT="1"/>
    <CONNECTOR CTYPE="SUBJOB_OK" MAX_INPUT="1" />
    <CONNECTOR CTYPE="SUBJOB_ERROR" MAX_INPUT="1" />
    <CONNECTOR CTYPE="COMPONENT_OK" />
    <CONNECTOR CTYPE="COMPONENT_ERROR" />
    <CONNECTOR CTYPE="RUN_IF" />
  </CONNECTORS>
  
  <PARAMETERS>
    <PARAMETER NAME="ADDRESSES" FIELD="TABLE" REQUIRED="true" NUM_ROW="3" NB_LINES="5" SHOW="true">
      <ITEMS BASED_ON_SCHEMA="false">
        <ITEM NAME="USERNAME" />
        <ITEM NAME="DOMAIN" />
      </ITEMS>
    </PARAMETER>
  </PARAMETERS>
  
  <CODEGENERATION/>
  
  <RETURNS>
    <RETURN NAME="NB_LINE" TYPE="id_Integer" AVAILABILITY="AFTER"/>
  </RETURNS>
  
</COMPONENT>
```

tTutorialRow_messages.properties:

```
LONG_NAME=Tutorial component
HELP=org.talend.help.TutorialRow
 
NB_LINE.NAME=Number of lines
ADDRESSES.ITEM.USERNAME=Username
ADDRESSES.ITEM.DOMAIN=Domain
ADDRESSES.NAME=Addresses
```

tTutorialRow_begin.javajet:

```
<%@ jet 
    imports="
        org.talend.core.model.process.INode 
        org.talend.core.model.process.ElementParameterParser 
        org.talend.core.model.metadata.IMetadataTable 
        org.talend.core.model.metadata.IMetadataColumn 
        org.talend.core.model.process.IConnection
        org.talend.core.model.process.IConnectionCategory
        org.talend.designer.codegen.config.CodeGeneratorArgument
        org.talend.core.model.metadata.types.JavaTypesManager
        org.talend.core.model.metadata.types.JavaType
        java.util.List 
        java.util.Map       
    " 
%>
<% 
    CodeGeneratorArgument codeGenArgument = (CodeGeneratorArgument) argument;
    INode node = (INode)codeGenArgument.getArgument();
    String cid = node.getUniqueName();  
    List<Map<String, String>> lines = (List<Map<String,String>>)ElementParameterParser.getObjectValue(node, "__ADDRESSES__");
%> 
java.util.List<String> addresses_<%=cid %> = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
<%
  for (int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++) {
    Map<String, String> line = lines.get(i);
%>
    addresses_<%=cid %>.add(<%= line.get("USERNAME") %> + "@" + <%= line.get("DOMAIN") %>);
<%
  }
%>
int nb_line_<%=cid %> = 0;
```

tTutorialRow_main.javajet:

```
<%@ jet 
    imports="
        org.talend.core.model.process.INode 
        org.talend.core.model.process.ElementParameterParser 
        org.talend.core.model.metadata.IMetadataTable 
        org.talend.core.model.metadata.IMetadataColumn 
        org.talend.core.model.process.IConnection
        org.talend.core.model.process.IConnectionCategory
        org.talend.designer.codegen.config.CodeGeneratorArgument
        org.talend.core.model.metadata.types.JavaTypesManager
        org.talend.core.model.metadata.types.JavaType
        java.util.List 
        java.util.Map       
    " 
%>
<% 
    CodeGeneratorArgument codeGenArgument = (CodeGeneratorArgument) argument;
    INode node = (INode)codeGenArgument.getArgument();
    String cid = node.getUniqueName();  
%>
    String[] adresses_<%=cid %> = addresses_<%=cid %>.toArray(new String[] {});
     
    System.out.print(nb_line_<%=cid %>++ + ": ");
    for (int i_<%=cid %> = 0; i_<%=cid %> < adresses_<%=cid %>.length; i_<%=cid %>++ )
    {
      System.out.print(adresses_<%=cid %>[i_<%=cid %>]);
      if (i_<%=cid %> < adresses_<%=cid %>.length-1) System.out.print(",");
    }   
    System.out.println();
```

tTutorialRow_end.javajet:

```
<%@ jet 
    imports="
        org.talend.core.model.process.INode 
        org.talend.core.model.process.ElementParameterParser 
        org.talend.core.model.metadata.IMetadataTable 
        org.talend.core.model.metadata.IMetadataColumn 
        org.talend.core.model.process.IConnection
        org.talend.core.model.process.IConnectionCategory
        org.talend.designer.codegen.config.CodeGeneratorArgument
        org.talend.core.model.metadata.types.JavaTypesManager
        org.talend.core.model.metadata.types.JavaType
        java.util.List 
        java.util.Map       
    " 
%>
<% 
    CodeGeneratorArgument codeGenArgument = (CodeGeneratorArgument) argument;
    INode node = (INode)codeGenArgument.getArgument();
    String cid = node.getUniqueName();  
%>   
    globalMap.put("<%=cid %>_NB_LINE",nb_line_<%=cid %>);
```

If I change the files name from:

```
tTutorialRow_java.xml
tTutorialRow_messages.properties
tTutorialRow_begin.javajet
tTutorialRow_main.javajet
tTutorialRow_end.javajet
```

to:

```
myProject_java.xml
myProject_messages.properties
myProject_begin.javajet
myProject_main.javajet
myProject_end.javajet
```

and update the folder name to myProject, adding the component no longer works. How can I add the component with a new name?

Thanks!

Comment: name must be same across all the files if it is differ then it will not shown, in pallet. can you explain how component is not working whether it is not displayed or not functioning according to code?

Comment: could you try to use tmyProject_ ?  I think it won't load if the name doesn't start with a "t"

Comment: That was it - I just needed to adjust the names of not only the file but the containing folder (for example tProjectName (which was the folder), tProjectName_begin.javajet, tProjectName_java.xml...etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that there are certain naming specifics/requirements for incorporating a custom component in Talend.

The following worked:

I had to include a folder inside of my main folder named `tProjectName`, containing:

```
tProjectName_begin.javajet
tProjectName_end.javajet
tProjectName_icon32.png
tProjectName_java.xml
tProjectName_main.javajet
tProjectName_message.properties
```

These files did not have to be changed at all inside from the format in the question section of this stackoverflow question.

Comment: Are you saying you had to add the "t" prefix? I was under the impression that there's no actual requirement for it to begin with a "t". The "t" prefix was originally to signify it was an official component delivered by Talend but the community seemed to pick it up as well. Or is there something else you did here? Could you list the naming specifics/requirements. Preferably with a link to where it's stated.

Comment: All that I did was rename the project, based on comments given earlier to this question.