# Talend - tTutorialRow custom component not working

Tags: talend

I've been following the steps within [this](https://help.talend.com/display/KB/How+to+create+a+custom+component) tutorial, but the final step is not working for me. I mean, Talend does not show the `tTutorialRow` component in the Palette.

I've been checking the Troubleshooting section of [this](https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Installing+a+custom+component) other document as suggested, with no success.

I've seen [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372516/naming-a-talend-custom-component-not-working-except-for-ttutorialrow) questions in SOF, but they are about going a step beyond, once the basic tutorial is running.

So, is there a way of watching what is happening? Some logs? Just to have hints about what is happening.

My Talend Open Studio (for Data Integration) version is 6.2.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem I was following the wrong tutorial (maybe it is outdated with regards to new versions of Talend).

I found [this](http://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-custom-component-writing-overview.html) other one who worked for me. It is about using the Component Designer perspective of the Studio.